# Power Apps call soap API

Tags: powerapps, power-platform

I want to call soap API in my power apps project. I tried to call rest API and I called there were no problem. I have no problem with soap API. I tried with custom connector but didn't work. Can anyone help me?

Call soap API in power apps

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the Code feature of Custom Connectors.

You need to transform the request and the response from SOAP to REST and vice-versa.

Here is an example:

```
public class Script : ScriptBase
{
    public override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync()
    {

        // Use the context to forward/send an HTTP request
        HttpResponseMessage response = await this.Context.SendAsync(this.Context.Request, this.CancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);

        // Do the transformation if the response was successful, otherwise return error responses as-is
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var contentAsString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);

            // Load XML string into an XmlDocument
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("SOAP-ENV", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("rsp", "http://url.com");

            xmlDoc.LoadXml(contentAsString);

            // Get the SOAP-ENV:Body node
            XmlNode bodyNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//SOAP-ENV:Body", nsmgr);

            // Get the GetListByNameResult node within the SOAP-ENV:Body node
            XmlNode resultNode = bodyNode.LastChild;

            // Create a JArray to hold the person objects
            JArray jsonArray = new JArray();

            if (resultNode != null)
            {
                resultNode = resultNode.LastChild;

                // Get all PersonIdentification nodes within GetListByNameResult
                XmlNodeList personNodes = resultNode.ChildNodes;

                // Iterate through each PersonIdentification node
                foreach (XmlNode personNode in personNodes)
                {
                    // Create a JObject to hold the person details
                    JObject jsonObject = new JObject();

                    // Iterate through each child node of the PersonIdentification node
                    foreach (XmlNode childNode in personNode.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        // Get the node name and value and add them as properties to the JObject
                        jsonObject[childNode.Name] = childNode.InnerText;
                    }

                    // Add the person object to the JArray
                    jsonArray.Add(jsonObject);
                }
            }

            // Serialize the JArray to a JSON string
            string jsonResult = jsonArray.ToString();

            // Example case: response string is some JSON object
            //var result = JObject.Parse(responseString);

            // Wrap the original JSON object into a new JSON object with just one key ('wrapped')
            var newResult = new JObject
            {
                ["results"] = jsonArray,
            };

            response.Content = CreateJsonContent(newResult.ToString());
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

That transforms this SOAP response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:s='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <GetListByNameResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org">
    <GetListByNameResult>
      <PersonIdentification>
        <ID>96</ID>
        <Name>Adam,Wolfgang F.</Name>
        <SSN>850-53-6279</SSN>
        <DOB>1991-02-12</DOB>
      </PersonIdentification>
      <PersonIdentification>
        <ID>188</ID>
        <Name>Adams,Phil H.</Name>
        <SSN>729-18-4435</SSN>
        <DOB>1972-11-24</DOB>
      </PersonIdentification>
    </GetListByNameResult>
  </GetListByNameResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Documentation of this feature is available here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/write-code